# Replace 6 pin on/off switch on Power Bank with 3pin or 2pin?

Tags: power, battery, switch

I'm looking to finish up my project in a box and i'm using a battery bank to power the Leonardo micro pro and other components. The bank has a little on/off which on it which has 6 pins underneath.

To make the project neater I wanted to fit an on/off rocker switch to the project box making it look better and providing a more substantial switch. Mostly the on/off rocker switches come in 3 pin or 2 pin connections though. Is it possible for me to join it the 6 pin combining some of the pins in some way or not? I can also pick up another battery shield which has a 3 pin switch, again could I combine that with a 2pin if required or do I need to use a 3 pin rocker with it?

Some pictures of what i'm (or could be) using

[image: Current power bank, on/off switch on the right side in the middle, 6 pins]
(Current power bank, on/off switch on the right side in the middle, 6 pins)
[image: Possible smaller power bank for my project with 3 pins on the on/off switch (bottom left side)]
Possible smaller power bank for my project with 3 pins on the on/off switch (bottom left side)
[image: Two pin rocker switch]
Two pin rocker switch
[image: Three pin, two way rocker switch]
Three pin, two way rocker switch

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like only 2 of the 6 pins are used. It's a simple on-off. The switch itself is a "Double Pole Double Throw", but the two poles are tied together to make it single pole (like a 3 pin switch), and one throw is ignored, making it 2-pin.

You can see on the underside of your board which pins are tied together with traces. Bridge those pin pairs to turn the board on.

Comment: Thanks Majenko, so basically the two pin rocker switch will work fine, just connect the middle pin to the two pins in the middle and the other pin to the two pins on the "on" side?

Comment: That is correct.

Comment: using a double pole switch creates built-in redundancy .... if one contact fails, then the switch will still operate normally

Comment: @jsotola The redundancy is generally an added bonus. Most people use a double pole switch when it's in that style because they are far more common, and hence cheaper.